# modify a string python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file structured in the following way:

```
num  mut
36    L
45    P
  ...
```

where num indicates the position of a mutation and mut indicates the mutation. I have to modify at the position num with the letter mut a string. I wrote the following code in python:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv')
df_tmp=df.astype(str)
df_tmp["folder"]=df_tmp["num"]+df_tmp["mut"] #add a third column
f = open("sequence.txt", 'r')
content = f.read()
for i in range(len(df)):
     num=df_tmp.num.loc[[i]]-13
     num=num.astype(int)
     prev=num-1
     prev=prev.astype(int)
     mut=df_tmp.mut.loc[[i]]
     mut=mut.astype(str)
     new="".join((content[:prev],mut,content[num:])) #this should modify the file
```

But it returns me

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

How can I solve?

Edit: maybe it is more clear what I want to do. I have to insert only the first mutation in my sequence, save it to a file, copy the file in a folder that is named as the third column (that I added in the code), make the same thing with the second mutation, then the third and so on. But I have to insert only one mutation at time.

Comment: your approach is really inefficient, you're looping and recreating the full string for each loop. the maximum complexity, assuming you change all characters would be `O(n**2)` while you can do it in `O(n)`

Comment: I edited the question, maybe now it is more clear why i use the loop @mozway

Comment: I see, I added an alternative to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### multiple mutations:

IIUC, you'd be better off pandas, convert your dataframe to dictionary, iterate and join:

```
# input DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [36, 45], 'mut': ['L', 'P']})

# input string
string = '-'*50
# '--------------------------------------------------'

# get the positions to modify
pos = df.set_index('num')['mut'].to_dict()
# {36: 'L', 45: 'P'}

# iterate over the string, replace hte characters if in the dictionary
# NB. define start=1 if you want the first position to be 1
new_string = ''.join([pos.get(i, c) for i,c in enumerate(string, start=0)])
# '------------------------------------L--------P----'
```

##### single mutations:

```
string = '-'*50
# '--------------------------------------------------'

for idx, r in df.iterrows():
    new_string = string[:r['num']-1]+r['mut']+string[r['num']:]
    # or
    # new_string = ''.join([string[:r['num']-1], r['mut'], string[r['num']:]])
    
    with open(f'file_{idx}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(new_string)
```

output:

```
file_0.txt
-----------------------------------L--------------

file_1.txt
--------------------------------------------P-----
```

Comment: In this case it adds the mutation and not substitute it. So for example in your string of 50 dash, it becomes of 51 @mozway

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with a sample file.csv and an empty sequence.txt file,

in your code first line from for loop

```
num=df_tmp.num.loc[[i]]-13
#gives an error since the num in that location is str, to correct that:

num=df_tmp.num.loc[[i]].astype(int)-13 
# I used astype to convert it into int first
```

After this the next error is in last line , the slice indices type error,
This is due to the fact that , the resulting prev and num you use to slice
the content variable is not a int, to get the int value add a [0] to it
in this way:

```
content="".join((content[:prev[0]],mut,content[num[0]:]))
```

There shouldn't be an error now.

Comment: now it gives me this: TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, Series found @Cranchian

Comment: at which line does this error pop up exactly?